# Build a sort selector depending variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery

For a project I need to make a sort of constructor to change some element in a page:

I have for example:

```
var element = ".h-event img";
var match   = "eq(0)";
var type    = "img";
var value   = "breakfast.png";
```

Allowing me to construct:

```
$(element).attr('src', value);
```

With this code:

```
if(type=='img') {
    $(element).attr('src', value);
}
```

The problem I have actually, is to use the `eq()` selector in jQuery by using by `match` variable.

How can I do that ?

This is what I already tried without success:

```
var match = (match=='') ? '': '.'+match+'.';
if(type=='img') {
    $(element)match.attr('src', item.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather use `:eq` selector for better concatenation:

```
var match = (match=='') ? '': ':'+match+'';
if(type=='img') {
  $(element+match).attr('src', item.value);
}
```

Comment: Good solution. But if i use Zepto, the `:eq` isn't available. Do you have another solution to support Zepto by using `eq()` please ? http://zeptojs.com/#eq

Comment: try using ` $(element)["eq(0)"]().attr('src', item.value);`

Comment: I can accept it for jQuery but if I would like to use `next`, `find()`, ... it will not work.

Comment: why not?? zeptojs do not supports it??